# Java Swing import CSS Style

Tags: java, css, swing, styles

How can I import my CSS style into a Java Application?

I have a normal CSS with the `JButton#btn` class styles and so on.

But how can I import it into my Application?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to turn the GUI with Java Swing with the file like in Python with the QT Framework

Swing doesn't work that way.  To change the look of a Swing GUI, we set a [Pluggable Look and Feel](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/02/27/laf.html).  It is true hat certain Swing components (including `JButton`) will render *parts of* HTML 3.2 and simple styles, and can indeed import stylesheets (and understand very basic CSS), it is implemented in a 'less than ideal' way.  For example, if a button styled with HTML/CSS is disabled, it does not gain the default 'disabled look' for a button.

I am led to understand the Java-FX GUI toolkit allows more the style you are after.  See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You don't import CSS into an application as a whole, CSS is applied directly to webpages. In order to insert an external CSS style into a page, you need to add this into `<head>` part

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

You can check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for more info about inserting CSS into a page.

Comment: No! I want to turn the GUI with Java Swing with the file like in Python with the QT Framework